# Rails: Missing region error AWS heroku paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I keep getting this error:

Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError (missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']):

my paperclip config looks like this:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => {
:bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
:secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
}
```

tried to add :region ENV['AWS_REGION']

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
:storage => :s3,
:region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
:s3_credentials => {
:bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
:secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
}
```

region in env is (when running heroku config)

AWS_REGION: us-east-1

tried to default config. created aws.rb in config/initializers

```
Aws.config.update({
region: 'us-east-1',
})
```

still doesn't work.

Comment: Probably you got an AWS outage as user `DaWolf85` said "This was US-East-1 that had the issue. It got fixed about 6 hours ago, though, so perhaps that's why you didn't find anything." here: https://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/3lofuv/amazon_web_services_go_down_taking_much_of_the/cv8fbuc

Comment: What happens if you add `:s3_region => 'us-east-1'` to the top level of the `paperclip_defaults` hash? (At the same level as `:s3_credentials`.)

Comment: It worked thanks. Image now loads on S3, still doesn't show on my app - but that's probably another reason I need to figure out.

Answer (score 10):

I got it working by performing the following:

1. Add to config/environments.production.rb

`config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
      :s3_credentials => {
        :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
        :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
}`

2. Set an additional heroku config by using: heroku config:set AWS_REGION=us-east-1
3. Ensure your region lines up with the latest regions at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#opsworks_region

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

You should try :s3_region not :region